# sql query to get data group by customer type and need to add default value if customer type not found

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table "Customers" with columns `CustomerID`, `MainCountry` and `CustomerTypeID`.

I have 5 customer types 1,2,3,4,5 .

I want to count number of customers of each country according to customer type. I am using the following query:

```
select count(CustomerID) as CustomerCount,MainCountry,CustomerTypeID 
from Customers 
group by CustomerTypeID,MainCountry
```

But some countries not have any customers, under type 1,2,3,4 or 5.

So I want to put a default value 0 for if customer type is not exist for that country.

Currently it is giving data as follows :-

```
CustomerCount   MainCountry CustomerTypeID
5695                    AU  1
525                     AU  2
12268                   AU  3
169                     AU  5
18658                   CA  1
1039                    CA  2
24496                   CA  3
2259                    CA  5
2669                    CO  1
10                      CO  2
463                     CO  3
22                      CO  4
39                      CO  5
```

As "AU" not have type 4 so I want a default value for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Country.MainCountry, CustomerType.CustomerTypeId, Count(T.CustomerID) As CustomerCount
From   (Select Distinct MainCountry From Customers) As Country
       Cross Join (Select Distinct CustomerTypeId From Customers) As CustomerType
       Left Join Customers T
         On Country.MainCountry = T.MainCountry
         And CustomerType.CustomerTypeId = T.CustomerTypeId
             -- Edit here
             And T.CreatedDate > Convert(DateTime, '1/1/2013')
             -- End Edit
Group By Country.MainCountry, CustomerType.CustomerTypeId
Order By MainCountry, CustomerTypeId
```

Comment: Many thanks @G Mastros, really awesome got answer with in 15 minutes. Again thanks, you are the champ :-)

Comment: Hello @G Mastros, it is not giving desire result if I am adding a where condition "where T.CreatedDate > convert(DATETIME, '1/1/2013')"

Comment: @Anand You should put that condition in the join clause, not the where clause.  I will edit my answer to show you where.

Answer (score 3):

You should JOIN your table with a table with TypeId's. In this case

```
select count(CustomerID) as CustomerCount,TypeTable.MainCountry,TypeTable.TId
from 
Customers 
 RIGHT JOIN (
            select MainCountry,TId from
            (
            select Distinct MainCountry from Customers
            ) as T1,  
            (
               select 1 as Tid
               union all 
               select 2 as Tid
               union all 
               select 3 as Tid
               union all 
               select 4 as Tid
               union all 
               select 5 as Tid
             ) as T2

) as TypeTable on Customers.CustomerTypeID=TypeTable.TId
                  and Customers.MainCountry=TypeTable.MainCountry 

group by TypeTable.TId,TypeTable.MainCountry
```

Comment: Thanks @Valex for quick response, but it is not giving desire result. I just want a default row for  "Au" and "CA" country for customer type 4, like 0  AU  0.

Comment: Hello Valex, it is not giving desire result if I am adding a where condition (where Customers.CreatedDate > convert(DATETIME, '1/1/2013') and  Customers.CreatedDate < convert(DATETIME, '12/31/2013') )

Comment: Means now it is not giving CustomerCount as 0 if CustomerTypeID 4 not contains by any country.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
with cuntry as (
Select Distinct MainCountry From Customers
),
CustomerType as (
(Select Distinct CustomerTypeId From Customers
),
map as (
select MainCountry, CustomerTypeId from cuntry,CustomerType 
)

select count(CustomerID) as CustomerCount,a.MainCountry,a.CustomerTypeID
from
map a left join Customers b on a.CustomerCount=b.CustomerCount and a.CustomerTypeID=b.CustomerTypeID
```